# SSD not showing up in left panel of windows explorer but is detected by disk manager and "Computer"

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, windows-explorer

My SSD is working great. I have Windows installed on it. Disk Manager and "My Computer" recognize it. 
But there is a strange issue : It is not showing up in the left part of the Windows explorer :

[image]

How can I put it back there ?

Comment: Does it show the disk as a removable? In system tray?

Comment: @Epoxy ! All my disks are shown as removable, I ejected (D:) which is another SSD and it disappeared. Why ?!

Comment: It's normal with Windows 10 when ssd is present. Did you install Intel Rapid Storage driver? If so, can you disable it and try again? In my system this is the culprit. It has its uses but not always required.